# Fill an array with doubles from scanner in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Im looking to fill an array with doubles from the user using Scanner. However, I am having difficulties because of Java's inability to alter array size. I need to get around this somehow. My idea for getting around this was to first have the user enter how many doubles he will be putting into the array.

```
System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to put in the array?: ");
int num = in.nextInt();
while(num >= 0) {
    double[] array[] = new double[num][];
    System.out.println("Enter the " + num + " numbers now.");
}
```

This is what I have so far but it is clear that it will not function as intended.

Comment: Your code will cause the compiler to explode. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Why not just use a list rather than an array?  Then fill the list up to the point that the user specifies.

Comment: Use an `ArrayList`, it will expand automatically and can easily be converted to an array when needed.

Comment: Im looking to fill an array with doubles from the user using Scanner.

Comment: Did you notice that your `array[]` is local to your loop? ... You should end up with its declaration outside of it.

Comment: Your code will run infinitely whenever num=>0 and if this condition is not met, this code shall not run. I cannot understand logic behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Decrement num or option (3)
2. Initialize your array outside the loop
3. Start saving numbers from array position 0

Here is how that would be done:

```
System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to put in the array?: ");
int num = in.nextInt();
int position = 0;
double[] array = new double[num];

while(position < num) {
    System.out.println("Enter the " + num + " numbers now.");
    array[position++] = in.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: He is asking for arrays, arrays are part of java-api, so they need a place in the world also, if he is learning to use array why we need to force him to use Collections?

Comment: Favor arrays over collections in this case. Collections are not a way for new people to skip learning how to use arrays.

Comment: If your array is to small, alloate a new (bigger) one and copy the contents from the old one into the new one and continue adding to the array until you are either done or have to resize it again-

Answer (score 0):

As you already know how many numbers the user will provide, Consider Using an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
for(int i = 0;i< num;i++){
    //Ask for a value
    //add that value to the list
}
```

Using a simple for loop, you can ask each value, an add it to the list.